# Why is average velocity not defined as the mean value of the velocity function?

Tags: calculus, physics

The mean value of a function is defined by $\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b {f(x)dx} $, but the average velocity of a moving object is defined by $\frac {\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ where $\Delta x$ is the change in the object's displacement and $\Delta t$ is the time interval in question.  Since the first method could give an exact average velocity and the second only gives an approximation, why is average velocity defined this way?

Comment: The ratio $\Delta x/\Delta t$ is more useful if you don't know $f(x)$.

Comment: Why do you say that the second only gives an approximation?

Comment: If you travel 100km in 1 hour, your average velocity is exactly, not approximately, 100km/hour, regardless of how you sped up or slowed down along the route.

Comment: It could happen that $\frac {\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ makes sense when $x(t)$ is not differentiable.  What @user170231 said.

Answer (score 9):

Let's look at the first formula. The velocity is a function of time, so $f(x)$ will be written as $v(t)$, $dx$ will become $dt$, and $b$ and $a$ are the final and initial times. Then $$v_{ave}=\frac 1{t_f-t_i}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}v(t)dt$$
By definition the velocity is the derivative of the position with respect to time $$v(t)=\frac {dx}{dt}=x'(t)$$
From the fundamental theorem of calculus $$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}x'(t)dt=x(t_f)-x(t_i)$$
Introducing the notations $\Delta t=t_f-t_i$ and $\Delta x=x(t_f)-x(t_i)$, you get $$v_{ave}=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$$
So the two formulas are equivalent.

Comment: I believe the definition for velocity that would be most true to OPs confusion would use $v(t) = \| x'(t) \|$, not the vector-valued one you give. It's ambiguously stated at best in the question, but a good answer should also address this, I think.

Comment: @WorldSEnder The absolute value would not work if the velocity changes sign. If you go from $A$ to $B$ and back to $A$, the average velocity is zero, while your definition would give a finite value. You are using the definition for the speed, not velocity.

Comment: you are right. As a non-native speaker, I sometimes use "velocity" when talking about speed, which I shouldn't. "Average speed" not average velocity is what I was referring to, and there is no ambiguity, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\frac1{b-a}\int_a^bv(t)\,dt = \left.\frac1{b-a}s(t)\right]_a^b$$
$$=\frac{s(b)-s(a)}{b-a}$$
$$=\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$$
so they're exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the sequencing of ideas.  Typically, the idea of average velocity is introduced *long* before the derivative (which is used to define instantaneous velocity) or the integral.  Indeed, the average velocity is often used to define the instantaneous velocity.  A fairly typical exposition runs something like the following:

1. Suppose that an object is moving back and forth along the number line.  At any moment in time, it is possible to measure the object's location.  Denote this by $s(t)$.  That is,
   $$ s(t) = \text{object's location at time $t$}. $$
2. If one wants to know how "fast" this object is moving, one must determine how far it has gone in some period of time (i.e. the units of velocity are $\text{distance}/\text{time}$).  Thus it is possible to measure velocities over intervals, e.g.
   $$ v_a^b = \frac{s(b) - s(a)}{b-a} = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}, $$
   where $a$ and $b$ are two moments in time at which the object's position can be measured, and $s(b) - s(a)$ is the displacement of the object between the two measurements.  Note that this is precisely the *average velocity* on the interval $[a,b]$.
3. The *instantaneous velocity* of the object at time $a$ is then defined to be the limit of the average velocities over intervals which "shrink to $a$":
   $$ v_a = \lim_{b\to a} \frac{s(b) - s(a)}{b-a}, $$
   assuming that this limit exists.
4. The *velocity function* is then defined to be the function $v$ which takes a time as input, and returns the instantaneous velocity as output, i.e.
   $$v(t) = \lim_{b\to t} \frac{s(b) - s(t)}{b-t} = s'(t). $$

In this style of exposition, it would be somewhat circular to then *redefine* the average velocity on an interval to be mean value obtained by integrating the velocity function.  Basically, it doesn't make sense to define the average velocity in terms of the velocity function, since the average velocity is used to define the velocity function.

Moreover, the average velocity (in terms of $\Delta s / \Delta t$) is defined whenever both $s(a)$ and $s(b)$ are defined.  However, in order for the average of the velocity function to be defined (that is, in order for $\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} v(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ to make sense *as an average velocity*), it must be the case that $v$ is the derivative of a differentiable function $s$.  As a silly example of how things can go wrong, suppose that $s$ is the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), pictured below:

[image: The Cantor Function]

This function satisfies $s(0) = 1$ and $s(1) = 1$.  Hence the average velocity over the interval $[0,1]$ is
$$v_0^1 = \frac{s(1) - s(0)}{1-0} = 1. $$
On the other hand, this function is *not* at any point of the Cantor set, and at all other points, the derivative of this function is zero.  Thus it makes little sense to attempt to understand the average velocity of an object whose position is given by the Cantor function in terms of the integral velocity (since the velocity is undefined at many points in the interval).  It may be worth noting, however, that in the context of the Lebesgue integral,
$$ \frac{1}{1-0} \int_{[0,1]} v(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
= \int_{[0,1]\setminus\text{Cantor set}} 0 \,\mathrm{d}t + \int_{\text{Cantor set}} v(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
= 0+0 = 0, $$
implying that the average velocity of this object over the interval is zero.  This might even be a sensible conclusion, but it doesn't really jive with the intuition that the object has moved one unit in a period of one second.

That being said, if an object's position, $s$, is differentiable and its instantaneous velocity, $v$, is given by $v = s'$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} v(t) \,\mathrm{d}t
&= \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} s'(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{b-a} \bigl( s(b) - s(a) \bigr) && \text{(Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)} \\
&= \frac{s(b) - s(a)}{b-a} \\
&= v_{a}^{b}.
\end{align}
Hence both notions of the average velocity agree in these cases.